# Get notified about changes in a google calendar

Tags: macos, google-calendar-api

I was wondering, is it possible to set up a Mac OS X app, to get notified when a user makes changes to a Google Calendar. Like what you can do with **EKEventStore**?

There’s a query method `+ (id)queryForCalendarListWatchWithObject:(GTLCalendarChannel *)` object, but I’m not really sure how you should set up the `GTLCalendarChannel` object.

Or is the only way, other than polling, to use push notifications?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ***Google Calendar API*** which provides push notifications that let you watch for changes to resources. This makes periodic polling unnecessary.

> You can use this feature to improve the performance of your application. **It allows you to eliminate the extra network and compute costs involved with polling resources to determine if they have changed.** Whenever a watched resource changes, the Google Calendar API notifies your application.

**To use this API, you need to:**

- [Register the domain of your receiving URL.](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#registering-your-domain) *Before you can set up a push notification channel, you must register the domain for any URLs you plan to use to receive push notification messages.*
- [Set up your receiving URL, or "Webhook" callback receiver.](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#receiving-notifications) *Whenever a watched resource changes, your application will receive a notification message describing the change. The Google Calendar API sends these messages as HTTPS POST requests to the URL you [specified as the "address"](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#address_prop) for this notification channel.*
- [Set up a notification channel for each resource endpoint you want to watch.](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#creating-notification-channels) *To request push notifications, you need to set up a notification channel for each resource you want to watch. After your notification channels are set up, the Google Calendar API will inform your application when any watched resource changes.*

When a calendar changes, it will notify your app and the app does an API call to get the update. You can use one of the [Google API client libraries](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/downloads)  to utilize push notifications.

Check these [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push) and [blog](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2013/07/google-calendar-api-push-notifications.html) about Google Calendar API Push notifications.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But the documentation says: ```Notifications are not 100% reliable. Expect a small percentage of messages to get dropped under normal working conditions. Make sure to handle these missing messages gracefully, so that the application still syncs even if no push messages are received.
``` So it's not reliable to build import on these notifications. Are they still useful? What is 'small percentage'? Is it a good idea to use them + rare polling (e.g. once an hour just in case)?